# Botão Marcar/Desmarcar checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho o botão marcar/desmarcar checkbox, ele está funcionando, mas após passar pela equipe de testes, foi pedido que ao marcar um ou mais checkbox com mouse, ao ser clicado no botão ele faça a Desmarcação e o mesmo comportamento quando todos checkbox estiverem marcados acionado pelo botão, se eu desmarcar 2 ou 3 checkbox com o mouse, ao acionar novamente o botão ele deve Desmarcar todos. Ou seja o botão irá desmarcar sempre que houver uma ação realizada primeiramente com o mouse.

O comportamento do botão deve ser igual ao checkbox do e-mail Hotmail.

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="checkAll(participante)"
     ng-model="selectedAll"
     ng-disabled="!participante.length">
     <span><i class="glyphicon"></i> Marcar/Desmarcar Todos</span>
  </button>
     </div>

    <input type="checkbox" 
     id="checkParticipantes"
     name="checkParticipantes" 
     title="Encaminhar para autorização"
     ng-hide="!(pessoa.show_ckeckbox && pessoa.idSituacaoPagamento !== '17')"
     ng-model="checkedParticipante[pessoa.idPessoaEvento]"
     ng-change="verificaParticipanteSelecionado(pessoa.idPessoaEvento)"/>
```

```
$scope.checkAll = function (itens) {
        var checkFalse = (typeof $scope.checkedParticipante[itens[0].idPessoaEvento] == 'undefined' || $scope.checkedParticipante[itens[0].idPessoaEvento] == false) ? true: false;
        itens.forEach(function (i) {
            $scope.checkedParticipante[i.idPessoaEvento] = (checkFalse) ? checkFalse : false;
        });
    };
```

Comment: A explicação está sem entender ou confusa ??